# Flutter Speech to Text in Arabic Language

Tags: flutter, dart, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, arabic-support

Is there is a way to convert speech into text using flutter (specially if the the speech in Arabic and also I want the resulted text in Arabic) I've found many resources that explains how speech to text in English but not Arabic so I hope anyone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Use Flutter [speech_to_text](https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text) library.

to change language, localeId = the ID of the Arabic language on this device:

```
var locales = await speech.locales();

// Some UI or other code to select a locale from the list
// resulting in an index, selectedLocale

var selectedLocale = locales[selectedLocale];
speech.listen(
    onResult: resultListener,
    localeId: selectedLocale.localeId,
    );
```